# How to write fields in Odoo with XMLRPC?

Tags: python, xml, rpc, xml-rpc, odoo-11

I want to overriding a line of invoice in account_invoice with write method.
The code :

```
 def modifyInvoice(id):

    invoiceLines = [(1,id,{
    'account_id': 636, 
    'name': "iPod2", 
    'quantity': 155,                                                         
    'price_unit': 17, 
    'product_id': 1})]

    vals = {
            'invoice_line_ids' : invoiceLines,
    }
    Invoice = call(url, "object", "execute", DB, uid, PASS, 'account.invoice', 'write', 
    vals)
    print('invoice ...', Invoice)
```

and here the error :
rgs, **kwargs)\nTypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'\n', 'message': "write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'", 'arguments': ["write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vals'"], 'exception_type': 'internal_error'}}

Please I need help !

Answer (score 2):

This is because you haven't passed the id of the invoice to be updated.
In this line pass it as this

```py
Invoice = call(url, "object", "execute", DB, uid, PASS, 'account.invoice', 'write', [[invoice_id],vals])
```

Check these docs: [Odoo XMLRPC](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/api/odoo.html)